# Copy SQL Server Table's Data to a New Table (in Code)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I could use your advice on an approach for copying data between tables. I'm *really* trying to avoid RDBMS-specific SQL... The 2 tables are the same in all respects except name.

Concept:

My application uses data from a table (let's call it `TableA`). But this reference data changes almost daily, so I want to copy yesterday's off to make room for toady's data.

Right now, I use SMO to make an exact copy of `TableA` (schema), with unique (using date) names for the table, indices, keys, etc. No problemo. If there are any problems updating `TableA` with today's data, I can always restore yesterday's `TableA` (`TableA_<yesterdayDate>`). Both tables are on the same database.

I can't just use SMO's `.rename`, because it won't rename all the keys & indices...

So much for the premise.

Desired:

A non-SQL statement way to do so. I am heavily invested in EF6/Code First in this application, but as the name of the table changes each day, I can't just add tables/classes in `DbContext` 'just in case'.

I just feel so *dirty* using low level SQL...

- SQL Server 2012
- VB2012
- EF6/Code First

P.S. I've tried a few times in the past to implement SQL statements (LINQ-ish) via the `DbContext`, and never got it to work-especially for SPs.

Comment: This seems a bit extreme. Certainly not something you should be doing as a standard solution. Can I ask why do you need this? i.e. Can you elaborate on "But this reference data changes almost daily, so I want to copy yesterday's off to make room for toady's data."?

Comment: @TomT, thanks for writing! A few times/day, I collect stats and store them in this table. There are thousands of rows, and actually a few more tables (that have slightly different schema). When putting new data in, I'll suspend client access to the table until either then new updated data is in OK, or if error, I put the old data back.

Comment: CodeFirst and the name of the table changes everyday??? EF when "new" tables are being used in the Schema??? Before you can copy entries in you have to get EF to see the NEW table.   Perhaps you might explain a little more ;-)

Comment: @philsoady, thanks for writing! I use EF for the main/production tables... I could do it programmatically with EF (adding new tables/classes/context), but that ends up being way too fragile. complicated, and inelagant... This copy operation is more for backups & restore. I'm pretty much resigned to using SQL directly, at this point... :(

Comment: You feel so dirty using SQL? You should feel dirty for doing whatever it is you're doing - archiving tables into named tables... you're totally missing the point of a database.

Comment: @ElectricLlama I'll give you that! :) So seeing what I'm doing, what is your suggestion to be able to go back to a specific backup and see data & be able to re-run the values?

Comment: Two suggestions: 1. Just do a full database backup and restore into a different DB as required. 2. Archive into table(s) which have an additional datestamped field to partition the data. Use a views referencing a single data constant in a table) to select the partition of data that you want. 3. Extend on this view idea and use a stored procedure to move data in and out of archive tables. Basically you want to avoid specially named tables - just put it into the same table with another datestamp field to partition the data and use other means to filter on that partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find a cleaner way to do this. I tried to encapsulate all the logic into a single Function that returns a boolean on success/failure. Please orgive the roughness of the code!

NewTableName is just **OldTableName_YYYMMDD**. I could have used "SourceTableName", but this is just the first hack at it.

```
 Public Function MoveAllRowsToNewTable(OldTableName As String, NewSchemaName As String, NewTableName As String, IndexColumnName As String) As Boolean
        ' OldTableName = "TableA", "TableB", ...
        ' NewSchemaName = "dbo"
        ' NewTableName = "TableA_20140325", etc.
        ' IndexColumnName = "ID" in my case, but whatever col is needed
        '
        Try
            '===
            '
            ' DROP target table (if exist)
            '
            If Me.DoesTableExist(NewSchemaName, NewTableName) Then
                Dim CmdQ = Me.ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DROP TABLE " & NewSchemaName & "." & NewTableName)
                log.Debug("DROPPED TABLE " & NewTableName)
            Else
                NewTableName = NewSchemaName & "." & NewTableName
                log.Debug("New table name: " & NewTableName)
            End If
            '
            Dim numRows As Int32 = 0 ' holds # of rows in SourceTable to check if copy OK
            Select Case OldTableName
                Case "TableA"
                    Try
                        '===
                        '
                        ' Count rows in source table
                        '
                        numRows = (Me.ctx.TableA).Count
                        '
                        '===
                        '
                        ' Copy rows in source table, creating new table in the process
                        '
                        CmdQ = "SELECT * INTO " & NewTableName & " FROM " & OldTableName
                        Me.ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(CmdQ)
                        '
                        ' create PK
                        '
                        Dim PKQ As String = "ALTER TABLE " & NewTableName & " ADD CONSTRAINT PK_" & NewTableName & "_ID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID)"
                        CmdQ = ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(PKQ.ToString)
                        '
                        ' create index
                        '
                        Dim NewTableIndexName As String = "idx_" & NewTableName.Replace(".", "_") ' indices can't have a '.' in them
                        Dim IdxQ As String = "CREATE INDEX " & NewTableIndexName & " ON " & NewTableName & " (" & IndexColumnName & ");"
                        CmdQ = ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(IdxQ.ToString)
                        '
                        ' verify rows copied
                        '
                        Dim RowQ As Int32 = Me.ctx.Database.SqlQuery(Of Int32)("SELECT COUNT(*) AS rows FROM " & NewTableName).FirstOrDefault
                        log.Debug("TargetTableRows: " & RowQ.ToString)
                        If numRows = RowQ Then
                            log.Debug("MATCH!" & RowQ)
                        Else
                            log.Debug("NO MATCH! numRows: " & numRows & " RowQ: " & RowQ)
                            '
                            ' rollback the move-the copy FAILED!
                            '
                            ' XXX to-do
                        End If
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        [...]
                    End Try
                    '
                Case "TableB"
                    [...]
```

I only have 3 source tables, so a Switch/Case is very practical in this early stage...

I'm still open to ideas, but I dug as far as I could, and I have to move on. Maybe I'll re-visit it something more elegant comes along!

Comment: @Moderators You can see that it is a VB.NET solution... :)